# can I use any of these services to call a script on the instance to be terminated to inform it of the pending termination?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm using an ASG for an internal application that will busier at some times than others. The instances all run crons that may take some time to complete (never more than 25 minutes).
When things get quiet, I need to be able to detect when an instance is going to be terminated so that I can let any crons finish and disable any new crons firing.
I see that there are lifecycle hooks that can fire using SNS, SQS or Lambda. I haven't used these services before - can I use any of these services to call a script on the instance to be terminated to inform it of the pending termination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a particular alarm triggered that terminates your instances, use lifecycle hooks to hold the termination for about 25-26 minutes and also with the same alarm triggered a lambda function. In that lambda function first identify the instances running under that ASG (using boto3) and with paramiko (python module to run commands on Linux machines) library try to issue a command to terminate the scripts in your instances